# ElectronJS: Operation not permitted

Tags: node.js, linux, electron

I've been developing an Electron app for Linux. The problem is: I can't execute an instruction because of this:

```
Error: socket: Operation not permitted
```

This might mean it needs sudo permissions. But since it is a desktop app, and I want to avoid this when I'll distribute it, is there a way to bypass this error, to execute it without sudo or automatically use it, in both development and production mode? If not, can I write a message which says it requires admin execution when I open its AppImage?

**@crimson589**

If I run dev mode with `sudo npm run electron:serve` it returns `Error: Failed to get 'appData' path`. If I run the AppImage with sudo, it works.

Comment: If you think it needs sudo, did your app work when you opened it with sudo?

Comment: @crimson589 Check question